# how to proof Σanbn is convergent with following conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ satisfy
(i):$\;a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$ is bounded for all $n$.
(ii):$\;\lim b_n=0$.
(iii):$\;|b_1-b_2|+|b_2-b_3|+\cdots+|b_n-b_{n+1}|+\cdots<∞.$
Prove that $Σa_nb_n$ is convergent.

I find it's like Dirichlet discriminant method，but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ with $S_0:=0$, then $|S_n|\leqslant M <\infty$ for all $n$ by assumption. We have for $m<n$,
\begin{align*}
\Big|\sum_{k=m}^n a_kb_k\Big|&=\Big|\sum_{k=m}^n (S_k-S_{k-1})b_k\Big|=\Big|\sum_{k=m}^n S_k b_k -\sum_{k=m}^n S_{k-1}b_k\Big|\\
&=\Big|S_{m-1}b_m+\sum_{k=m}^{n-1} S_k(b_k-b_{k+1})+S_n b_n\Big|\leqslant |S_{m-1}b_m|+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} |S_k|\cdot|b_k-b_{k+1}|+|S_n b_n|\\
&\leqslant M|b_m|+M \sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\cdot|b_k-b_{k+1}| + M|b_n|.
\end{align*}
 Taking $m, n\to \infty$ both sides, we get
$$\Big|\sum_{k=m}^n a_kb_k\Big| \to 0,$$
hence the we get the convergence of series.